# Unable to deploy application with spring-data-mongodb 1.10.0

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to migrate from **spring-data-mongo 1.9.5** to **1.10.0** in order to use the **noCursorTimeout()** method in Query class, but I'm getting an error trying to deploy the application:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.util.properties.MongoPropertiesConfiguration#7dc57a65' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/properties-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplateReplicaSet' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplateReplicaSet' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mongo-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'xxxxxx': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.()
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
>       ... 68 more

It seems that **MongoRepositoryFactoryBean** doesn't have a default constructor anymore.

This is my spring mongo configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.10.xsd">

<bean id="mongoServer" class="com.mongodb.ServerAddress">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <constructor-arg type="int" name="port" value="27017"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoServerList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="mongoServer"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredential" class="com.mongodb.MongoCredential">
    <constructor-arg name="mechanism" value="#{T(com.mongodb.AuthenticationMechanism).SCRAM_SHA_1}"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="userName" value="user"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" name="source" value="myDB"/>
    <constructor-arg type="char[]" name="password" value="xxxxx"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredentialList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="mongoCredential"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<!-- MongoClient -->
<bean id="mongoClient" class="com.mongodb.MongoClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoServerList"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoCredentialList"/>
</bean>
<!-- MongoDbFactory -->
<bean id="mongoDbFactory" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongoClient"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="myDb"/>
</bean>
<bean id="mappingContext"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>
<bean id="typeInformationMapper" class="com.example.util.typemapper.AnnotationTypeInformationMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="basePackagesToScan">
        <list>

            <value>com.example.entity</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="defaultMongoTypeMapper"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
    <constructor-arg name="typeKey" value=
        "_class" />
    <constructor-arg name="mappers" >
        <list>
            <ref bean="typeInformationMapper" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="mappingMongoConverter"
      class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mappingContext"/>
    <property name="typeMapper" ref="defaultMongoTypeMapper"/>
</bean>
<!-- MongoTemplate -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" primary="true">
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    <property name="writeConcernResolver" ref="writeConcernResolver"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoTemplateReplicaSet" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" primary="false">
    <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
    <property name="writeConcernResolver" ref="writeConcernResolver"/>
    <property name="readPreference" ref="readPreferenceSecondary"/>
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mappingMongoConverter" />
</bean>

<bean id="writeConcernResolver" class="com.example.MyWriteConcernResolver">

</bean>

<bean id="readPreferenceSecondary" class="com.mongodb.TaggableReadPreference.SecondaryPreferredReadPreference"/>

<mongo:repositories base-package="my.repository.package.*"/>
```

I'm using **Spring 4.3.6.RELEASE** and **java-mongo-driver 3.3.0**

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hello @Madbreaks, yes I had to change the version of spring-data-commons as well. 
These are the versions I used: 

spring: 4.3.6.RELEASE,
spring-data-commons: 1.13.0.RELEASE,
spring-data-mongodb: 1.10.11.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks.  You should add that as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this changing the version of spring-data-commons as well.

These are the versions I used:
 
spring: **4.3.6.RELEASE**, 
spring-data-commons: **1.13.0.RELEASE**, 
spring-data-mongodb: **1.10.11.RELEASE**

Answer (score 0):

Try Spring-Data-mongo 1.10.12 rather 1.10.0. And Update the mongo-java driver to 3.4.0

Comment: Thanks @Ash, sorry I didn't answer before. I managed to make this work upgrading the version of spring-data-commons as well, no changes to mongo-java driver needed.